# cuda not available when installing fastai or pytorch using anaconda

Tags: pytorch, anaconda3, fast-ai

I want to install fastai package for machine learning tasks. I am using anaconda3 as my package manager.
My GPU is **NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU**.
This GPU is listed as cuda compatible on the nvidia cuda compatible list on this website [text](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)
But when I install the libraries, I always get cuda as not available.

I have tried installing fastai through multiple channels, like,

```
conda install -c fastchan fastai

conda install -c nvidia fastai anaconda
```

but every time when I check for cuda availability using

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

it returns false.

I have also tried installing only pytorch cuda from the official get started locally website
[text](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

but even after installing only pytorch using the above command, cuda is still not available.

I have used `conda clean`  command to clear index files and tarballs. The problem still persists.

How do I enable cuda for pytorch, specifically when using it with the **fastai library**?

Additional information,
when using `conda list` in environment where I installed fastai, pytorch is listed as

```
pytorch                   1.12.1          cpu_py310h5e1f01c_0
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this or similar cases you have several options:

1. Clean install supported version of PyTorch with CUDA using
   instruction from site, check `torch.cuda.is_available()`  and next
   install new package, by `pip install fastai` **or**
2. Right after your
   installation, uninstall cpu version of PyTorch and install GPU supported **or**
3. (Most complicated) Replace requirements in various setup scripts by your demands. E.g. remove unnecessary conditions or change in setup.py, requirements.txt, different *.ini *.yaml in source code.

Comment: Can you please explain the third point. I am still new to managing packages, and don't know what you mean by setup scripts.
Also, where can I get GPU supported version of pytorch. So far, everytime I install pytorch(through conda), I get the CPU version only. Thanks

Comment: for installing PyTorch you just need to pick your CUDA version in here https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

Comment: I used pip to install cuda version of pytorch and then fastai. And torch.cuda.is_available() is returning true now. So I am not uninstalling pytorch now. Thank you for your help.